# Place the label and number of captions at the margin in ConTeXt

Tags: captions, context

I have some tables with captions in a document, and I want the labels and numbers to be placed at the (left) margin, right aligned, while the text of the caption would be at the text area, left aligned. Something like

```
               Bla bla bla bla bla...

               ---------------
               |   1  |   2  |
               ---------------
               |   3  |   4  |
               ---------------
    Table 1    Table sponsored by ConTeXt.

               Bla bla bla bla bla...
```

But while I have found the `\numbercommand` can be used to toy with the number, the *label* of the caption would be still on the text area. So the farthest I can get is something like

```
               Bla bla bla bla bla...

               ---------------
               |   1  |   2  |
               ---------------
               |   3  |   4  |
               ---------------
          1    Table Table sponsored by ConTeXt.

               Bla bla bla bla bla...
```

Is there some dark trick I can use to achieve what I want?

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what you actually want without a MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name “Table” comes from the associated label text.  You can easily clear it with `\setuplabeltext[en][table=]`.

```
\showframe

\setuplabeltext[en][table=]

\setupfloat
  [table]
  [location=flushright]

\define[1]\floatnumbercommand{\llap{#1\hskip\leftmargindistance}}

\setupcaption
  [table]
  [width=\textwidth,
   distance=0pt,
   numbercommand=\floatnumbercommand]

\starttext

Bla bla bla bla bla...

\startplacetable
  [title={Table sponsored by ConTeXt.}]
  \startTABLE
    \NC 1 \NC 2 \NC\NR
    \NC 3 \NC 4 \NC\NR
  \stopTABLE
\stopplacetable

Bla bla bla bla bla...

\stoptext
```

[image]